# Get a specified rows amount from an array

Tags: arrays, range, rows

I have an array with 1000 rows like this and I want to convert into a string but only 50 rows of it.

```
 $thearray = Array
        (
          [0] => row1
          [1] => row2
          [2] => row3
          [3] => row4
          [4] => row5
          [5] => row6
          ...
          [999] => row1000
        )
```

The output should be like I would use:

```
$string1 = implode(',', $thearray);
```

But as said I need `$string1` to have only 50 rows from array and if is possible, to get them randomized. I need some advices. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, see comments in code for explanations and http://3v4l.org/hjuv6 for a demonstration

```
// Lets create a dummy array
$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
  $array[] = $i;
}

// Lets make a randomized temporary array
$backUpArray = $array;
$tempArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {

  // Select random Index
  $randomIndex = rand(0 , count($backUpArray));
  // Copy it to the temp array
  $tempArray[] = $backUpArray[$randomIndex];
  // Delete the row from our backup
  unset($backUpArray[$randomIndex]);
  // Reorganize the key indexes
  $backUpArray = array_values($backUpArray);
}


$string1 = implode(",", $tempArray);

var_dump($string1);
```